# what do users expect to find on a "contact us" page?

Tags: analytics, contact-us

My contact us page has a 90% hard bounce rate.

What do users expect to find on the contact us page?

I would like to reduce the bounce rate and engage the visitors more.

Comment: Business Name, Business Address, **DIRECT** phone number, Email address, Hours of Operation, maybe the name of a person they can expect to speak to, and maybe an electronic contact form.

Comment: I'd argue a high bounce rate means the page is succesful. They came to find contact information. And found it (as they haven't had to go to other pages on the site).

Comment: What information are you showing on your contact us page right now? And like @DA01 mentioned you can't assume the page is unsuccessful by it's bounce rate.

Comment: I think you also need to think about why they would want to look at a contact us page:  if its a pure e-commerce site then they shouldn't need contact information if the site handles the transaction well.

Comment: That's the thing - it's an e-commerce site.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first question you need to ask is whether they were already on their way out when they came to this page.

For example, if they're coming here to get your phone number so they can make a call or email/postal address so they can write to you, it's quite likely that once they've got that bit of info, then the next thing they'll do is leave the site so they can contact you.

They've already made the decision as to what to do next. Going to your contact page is merely providing the information required to carry out that decision; leaving the site after browsing to the contact page is just a natural progression from there.

The bounce rate from the contact page is irrelevant; what you need to do is track back a step to see what pages they were on prior to the contact page, and find out what it was about *those* pages that makes people want to contact you (rather than continue with their order).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what users expect, but the best way is to talk with them. If you can identify them (for example, if you have a registration/signup process), you can set up quick interviews with a representative sample.

People like to help out, but if you have something to offer, that will make them more likely to talk with you.

Some other things to think about:

- Is the bounce rate at a similar level on other pages?
- Is it clear that this is a contact-us page?
- Are there so many fields to fill out that it scares people away?
- Look at the rest of the site and see if the overall design is engaging. Think about what a typical user wants, and what sort of engagements make sense. In some cases, people just want to read what you have, but there's not enough of a reason for them to contribute anything or ask questions.